# Using OpenCV with Cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile a very simple C++ OpenCV application with Cmake.

My *CMakeList.txt* file is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(2.8)
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)

add_executable(basic_opencv basic_opencv.cxx)
target_link_libraries(basic_opencv PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_include_directories(basic_opencv PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

However, it seems that `OpenCV_INTALL_PATH` value is something relative to the cmake config file `/usr/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake`, which ends being `/`, so `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` is set to `//include/opencv4` which does not exist.

It should be on my computer `/usr/include/opencv4`.

Is there something wrong with my installation ? Should I change the .cmake file by myself ? I find it weird because I installed OpenCV via arch package-manager, so I'd expect it to be well-configured.

Comment: `//include.opencv4` is still OK. The issue is that the package is not found properly. Probably some of the variables were manually set and then `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` is wrong. The fact that it is equal to `/` says as much.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "is still OK" ? I did not touched the .cmake file so I'm quite surprised that it does not work "out-of-the-box"

Comment: Just a guess: It could be that `OpenCVConfig.cmake` script has been written/generated for **much newer CMake**, than of 2.8. If CMake itself generates such script, then it puts some version checks into it. If possible, change minimum version in your `CMakeLists.txt` to 2.8.12, or, better, to 3.0.

Comment: It is an OK path for CMake to generate, despite the double `//`. The variables are wrong, but we don't know with this information why is it so. We don't know for instance what CMake generated from a fresh start.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it doesn't help, I even tried with 3.13.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I think the reason the variables are wrong is that `OpenCVConfig.cmake` sets `OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH` to `${OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH}/../../../`, and as `OpenCVConfig.cmake` is in `/usr/lib/cmake/`, it yields `/`. I think the cmake script doesn't "expect" to be here. But why is that so ? Isn't it generated so that it points to the right place when executed ?

Comment: There is a mistake somewhere then. Either the packager or the cmake file is wrong :/

Comment: Looks like `OpenCVConfig.cmake` script is simply **broken**. It is not your fault, but  we can only guess what is the reason (OpenCV scripts, arch packaging scripts, or both). BTW, if your `OpenCVConfig.cmake` looks like [that pattern](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in), then it has note that `include_directories` is not needed for "CMake >= 2.8.11". If your requirement for minimal CMake version is 2.8.11 (or more), you could safely omit `target_include_directories`, which uses `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess it means that I have to create a OpenCV import script myself.